# Yepnope Javascript does not call complete function on css files when called twice

Tags: yepnope

I have yepnope to dynamically load css and js files. My yepnode calls on a specific event (button-click for eg:).

When I call for the very first time (js, css) - it loads file - I can see css properly done.

However, when the event is triggered second time which calls yepnope again - it just fails to download css again (or does not even use the older one).

Js works fine second time too when called. But css does not work.

However when I call injectcss in the callback of the js call, it injects again forcefully but it defeats the entire purpose of the speed.

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/127

Comment: Appart from the github bug bostet by Tzrik this issue may also be part of the cause: https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/162